# fs.writeFileSync Doesn't Write String With Escaping Backslashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, escaping, fs

In my program I'm trying to write a string that represents a regular expression exactly as it is written into a file. This means preserving **any** backslashes that occur in the string. However, when I try to write this string to a file, each pair of backslashes has one less backslash than it should.

My example to demonstrate this problem is like so:

```
let filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'output.js');
let outputString = "\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{4}";
fs.writeFileSync(filepath, outputString, 'utf-8');
```

The output result is:

```
\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4}
```

Is there some option I can pass to `fs.writeFileSync` to maintain all characters in the string to write to the file?

I realize one solution might involve escaping all possible characters in this string with a library like [js-string-escape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-string-escape), but since these particular strings represent regular expressions is it *really* safe to do so? I don't want to alter them or their functionality in any way.

*note:* I realize this output isn't really valid JavaScript, but it's a somewhat contrived example of what I am really trying to do. This small snippet of code just best demonstrates the issue at hand.

Comment: It is maintaining all the backslashes already. Your string `outputString` at no time had double backslashes in it: those were removed when JavaScript parsed the string constant, leaving the single backslashes.

Comment: Not at all related to your question, but I would HIGHLY advise against using writeFileSync.  It can completely lock up your entire application if you get lots of traffic.  Really it's only suitable in the app bootstrapping process.

Answer (score 2):

If you want two backslashes in the outputString, four backslashes are nedded.
Ex.:

```js
let filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'output.js');
let outputString = "\\\\d{3}(-|\\\\s)?\\\\d{3}(-|\\\\s)?\\\\d{4}";
fs.writeFileSync(filepath, outputString, 'utf-8');
```

The output result will be:

```
\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{4}
```

One backslash skip the follow backslash...